# DataTable Formatting Issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to generate a DataTable from another DataTable. The code goes through and grabs certain field from each row of the original datatable. It then takes these, converts as necessary, and places them as a new row in the new datatable. I have gone through and watched the workRow variable as it is added to the new table. It always has values in it. However, by the end of the loop, the new dataGridViewSorted has nothing in it.

I have used this general code on another DataTable, and it works. This leads me to believe that there is some thing wrong with my original data table which has one column of strings and another column of strings. The original DataTable does not allow me to do dataTable.DefaultView. However, I can access all of the elements of the **original** only if I grab each of the rows and add them to a custom collection. That custom collection code is below as well.

Does anyone know what could be wrong with my original datatable that would disable me from reproducing it as a datatable, but allow me to pull items as a custom collection?

Here is my code:

```
DataRow workRow;
dataGridViewSorted.Columns.Add("house");
dataGridViewSorted.Columns["house"].DataType = typeof(string);
dataGridViewSorted.Columns.Add("VOLUME");
dataGridViewSorted.Columns["VOLUME"].DataType = typeof(double);

foreach (DataRow row in dataGridViewData.Rows)
{
    workRow = dataGridViewSorted.NewRow();
    workRow["house"] = row["house"].ToString();
    if (row["VOLUME"] == DBNull.Value) {
        //fixes null value error
        row["VOLUME"] = 0; 
    } 
    workRow["VOLUME"] = Convert.ToDouble(row["VOLUME"].ToString());
    dataGridViewSorted.Rows.Add(workRow);
}



        foreach (DataRow row in dataGridViewData.Rows)
        {
            tempHouse = (string)row["house"];
            tempHouse = tempSecurity.Substring(tempHouse.IndexOf(" ") + 1, 2);
            //creates DataItem for the collection based on house and volume
            MV.pieData.Add(Shadow_App.MainView.DataItem.createDataItem(tempHouse, Convert.ToDouble((string)row["VOLUME"])));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked to make sure that the DataTable does not have nested objects in it? This is basic formatting issue, and could result in nothing be shown in DataGridView.